# Align multiple divs over each other and 1 of them should auto growth

Tags: html, css

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65pg5p8p/4/) with the example I'm struggling with as it's a bit hard to explain. I though it wasn't that hard to create but the reality tells me something different :').

I have 2 columns which floats to the left in order to create 2 columns. The left column contains several div's (a red ring, a line and a dot) and the right column contains some content.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftColumn">
        <div class="ring"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
        <p>Some text here which can be extremely large... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ring{
  margin: 15px auto 0;
  border-radius: 55%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.line{
  width:1px;
  padding:1px;
  border-left:2px solid #FFF;
  border-right:2px solid #FFF;
  background-color:#000;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
}

.dot{
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 55%;
  border: 0px solid red;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.container{
  width:500px; 
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.leftColumn{
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}

.rightColumn{
  width:66%;
  float:left;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to position all the div's of the left column on top of each other but all in the middle aligned of the left column (first the 'ring' in the middle aligned, the line on top of the ring and horizontal in the middle aligned and finally the dot in the center of the ring).

One of the div's (with the class 'line') should have a height till the bottom of the container. This container grows automatically once there is more text given in the second column.

Is this even possible to do without using any javascript? I'm getting into a fight all the time with the position absolute and the auto growth and don't know how to combine them. Or am I using the wrong order of these items?

Answer (score 1):

You want to have it absolutely positioned. Have a look at this:

```css
.ring{
  margin: 15px auto 0;
  border-radius: 55%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.line{
  width:1px;
  padding:1px;
  border-left:2px solid #FFF;
  border-right:2px solid #FFF;
  background-color:#000;
  margin:0 0 0 80px;
  position: absolute;
  height:10000px;
}

.dot{
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 55%;
  border: 0px solid red;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container{
  width:500px; 
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.leftColumn{
  width:33%;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
}

.rightColumn{
  width:66%;
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftColumn">
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightColumn">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ut elit non felis auctor hendrerit. In non gravida nunc. Fusce euismod nulla ac quam tristique ullamcorper. Cras gravida est nec erat posuere, vel volutpat felis maximus. Donec dapibus lorem quis sagittis accumsan. Aenean suscipit iaculis sapien, ac tempus quam. Sed id nibh eu dui euismod posuere quis id odio. Cras feugiat rhoncus nisi, sed luctus dui iaculis non. Praesent sollicitudin nulla nec elit ornare porta. Morbi id tortor ultricies, convallis tellus in, ullamcorper mi. Aenean facilisis diam sed est facilisis lobortis. Aliquam convallis tortor vitae ullamcorper accumsan. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent scelerisque pulvinar dui, ut efficitur risus iaculis aliquet. Phasellus tempor turpis ipsum, in sodales sem egestas id. Mauris auctor ut enim in lacinia. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I'm checking the code snippet, the line is way to height, also, it doesn't float over the ring and the black dot is not in the middle of the ring...

Comment: @PazcaldeJonge Check the updated answer once? May be refresh and see?

Comment: Checked... the line is the correct height but can you also float the line over the ring? so actually, the top should be 0 of the line...?

Comment: btw.. If im copying the css of your answer into jsfiddle, it still doenst work... :/

Comment: Wait... What's happening now?